# IOS Iphone app randomly hangs indefinitely

Tags: ios

App being built on Xcode 4, for a base IOS level of 4 and above, tested on a variety of IPhones. Info in app is loaded from a JSON feed.

In my attempts to track down what's happening I've repeatedly debugged through this app, a fairly basic one that has a few views, overall nothing amazing or new in it as far as apps go.

The problem manifests itself occasionally, a lot of the time in our testing it has been if we've turned off Wifi to test on a cellular connection the app will hang when loading.

What happens is that the splash screen appears and the white spinning activity wheel spins as if it's loading the ad (an ad is displayed as part of the overall loading process) but it just sits there spinning.

So, most obvious question, is the ad the problem? Is it large or loading slowly? No, the JSOn feed is speedy (we check every time the app hangs and inbetween times as well to make sure it's all loading ok) and the ad is about 20k.

Debugging gets as far as the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method which I'll list below, it reaches the end of that method and the debugger essentially reports nothing else. It just sits there, nothing visible in the XCode debug navigator, no break points hit.

If step through that method, once it gets to the end it goes about 6-7 steps into compiled code then simply does the same thing.

Here's the code from that method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions { 

    [self loadData];

    splashViewController = [[OurSplashViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    splashViewController.delegate = self;

    OurWebViewController *webViewController = (OurWebViewController *)[[[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:2] topViewController];
    webViewController.url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://m.testURL.com/this_app/"];
        webViewController.path = @"/MyPath/Sample";

    [window addSubview:splashViewController.view];
        [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

So, it gets to the 'YES' of that method and then the debugger sails off into the land of ones and zeroes, reporting nothing back and hanging the app.

Has anyone got any idea what could be causing this?

UPDATE:

Seem to have isolated that the hanging comes down to a JSON call that is sent but no response is received. So my code should handle that after a while.

Here's the JSON code, maybe someone can notice something I'm missing in there:

```
- (void)fetchWithURL:(NSURL *)URL {
     if (!URL) {
        return;
    }

    self.jsonURL = URL;

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]     initWithURL:self.jsonURL];
    if (timeout) {
        [request setTimeoutInterval:timeout];
    }
    [request addValue:@"gzip" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];   

    connection_ = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request 
                                              delegate:self 
                                      startImmediately:YES];
    [request release];

    if (connection_ != nil) {
        if ([self.delegate     respondsToSelector:@selector(JSONFetchWillBeginDownload:)]) {
            [self.delegate JSONFetchWillBeginDownload:self];
        }
        receivedData_ = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    } else {
        if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(JSONFetch:downloadDidFailWithError:)]) {
            [self.delegate JSONFetch:self downloadDidFailWithError:[NSError errorWithDomain:NSURLErrorDomain code:NSURLErrorUnknown userInfo:nil]];
        }
    }
}
```

According to Charles the reason for the failed response was:

Client closed connection before receiving entire response

I wonder is my timeout period too short?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like my timeout period was too short for the ads and as a result if the user was off WiFi then the JSON took a little too long to load, causing the issue.

Fixed it by upping the timeout to a normal level.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) Proxy for debugging the data exchange with your remote services and the ad-server.

See this [tutorial](http://blog.mediarain.com/2009/08/iphone-http-connection-debugging/) for setting everything up.

Comment: This is for debugging on my local machine? Unfortunately it rarely happens on local, mainly when it's on actual IPhones for testing.

Comment: No, Charles can be used for both, actual device and when within the simulator. Try it, it will be of great value for you!

Comment: Go to *Help | Local IP Address..* in Charles to determine your local IP address.  Then open the Settings app on your device and go to *Wi-Fi* and tap on the disclosure arrow for your network.  Under *HTTP Proxy*, select *Manual*, put the IP address into the Server field and the default port for Charles is 8888.  Ensure that *Mac OS X Proxy* isn't selected in the Proxy menu in Charles, as this will just clutter up the logging with requests from your local machine.

Comment: Thanks guys, going to give Charles a go. Hopefully will help track this down.

Comment: Have Charles up and running successfully, very handy piece of software so thank you for the suggestion. However, the issue seems to occur very very infrequently on WIFI. Which would lead someone to think it was slow data speeds...but the app just hangs and hangs when on edge or 3G...but not every time!

Comment: Have Charles throttling speed down to 8kbps and it's still working fine. Soo as I switch to 3G / edge it occurs every now and then!

Comment: It appears that your app needs to handle timeouts properly then as they can and will happen in real-world-scenarios.

Comment: There are two calls to the JSON feed, one for the feed content and one for the ad URL in the content. Both have timeouts accommodated for, the app doesn't crash or anything, it just sits there.

Comment: Have you tested the timeouts by putting excessive delays in the server-side code?  Have you tested total network failures by switching airplane mode on?  Getting it to consistently fail would be a good step along the way.

Comment: Replicated the problem....the second JSON request is sent but I am getting no response. Will edit the original question with code...

Answer (score 1):

If the spinning wheel (which is presumably part of the splash screen) is appearing, then the method you've posted is obviously working.  If the splash screen is not disappearing, the obvious place to start debugging is in the code that sends the request and the code that receives the response then dismisses the splash screen.

Use a proxy like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to verify that the request is going out and a response is coming back.  If that is the case, debug the code that receives the response and dismisses the splash screen.  If that isn't the case, debug the code that sends the request.

If you don't get anywhere, I suggest posting the relevant code.

Comment: Looks like it might be related to ICloud....I finally managed to replicate it on the phone and this url is coming up and the app is hanging:https://p04-ubiquity.icloud.com:443

Comment: Scratch that Icloud theory...was just the phone checking the cloud, wasn't interfering